# What is difference between render & render_to_string?

Tags: python, django

Currently I have referencing some old project created in django 1.9 version of my company and I have found that they have used render_to_string function many times as of now I am using render function but I have never used render_to_string.

Example code of render_to_string function is as below.

```
return HttpResponse(render_to_string('sales/sale.html', {'sale_id' : sale_id, `unique_number`:uni_id}, RequestContext(request)))
```

I have tried to search online find answer but not able to find any perfect answer.

What is difference between both these function & how they behave ?

When to decide which function is best suitable to use in project ?

Thanks.

Comment: `render_to_string` renders it to a string, whereas `render` wraps it in a `HttpResponse`.

Comment: What was unclear in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/templates/#django.template.loader.render_to_string)?

Comment: Your example will not work with Django 1.10+ (you would have to replace `RequestContext(request)` with `request`. Since you need to update the code, it would be more readable to replace `HttpResponse(render_to_string(...))` with `render(...)` at that point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can check the [source code of **`render`** [GitHub]](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/3.0.x/django/shortcuts.py#L14-L20):

> ```
> def render(request, template_name, context=None, content_type=None, status=None, using=None):
>     """
>     Return a HttpResponse whose content is filled with the result of calling
>     django.template.loader.render_to_string() with the passed arguments.
>     """
>     content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)
>     return HttpResponse(content, content_type, status)
> ```

In essence `render` thus calls `render_to_string(..)` with the `template_name`, `context`, `request`, and `using` as parameters, and then constructs a `HttpResponse` with that result and optionally a `content_type` and `status`. It is thus a shortcut that combines the two.

Comment: So how to decide when to use render or render_to_string ?

Comment: @Moon: if you want to generate a `HttpResponse`, then normally you use `render`, `render_to_string` is used when you do not plan to make a response. For example to render a template for an email, a subpart of the template, etc.

Comment: Thanks @ Willem, I also temporary assigned return value from both render & render_to_string into two different variable & able to figure out difference between those two.